# How to read int list from command line in Scala

Tags: scala

How to read integer list from command line ?

Like "1 2 3 4 5\n"

The excepted type in return is List[Int]

Comment: You should accept one of the given answers if your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 7):

Save this Scala script

```
val xs: List[Int] = args(0).split(' ').toList.map(_.toInt)
println(xs)
```

as `split.scala` and run it as (on Windows)

```
scala.bat split.scala "1 2 3 4 5"
```

The output is

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution where you can filter to escape the `\n`.

```
val input = "1 2 3 4 5\n"
val myList = input.filter(_!='\n').split(' ').map(_.toInt).toList
```